# Default Enum type, why this code does not compile?

Tags: c#, enums

I defined an Enum. I also have 2 methods:

1. method 1 -  will get the enum type - enum default type is int so it will print `System.Int32`
2. method 2 - will have switch case that compare the enum type with simple number - so in case the enum is int the switch case need to be compile with not problem and without any casting.

But this code does not compile and I get two errors ( the error point on the case 1 and case 2 in the switch case )

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Color'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Someone can explain why I get an error even if the `Color` type is `int` ?

To compile this code I need to make casting to the `Color` to `int`.

The code:

```
public enum Color
{
    RED,            // 0
    BLUE,           // 1
    GREEN           // 2
};

Color color = Color.BLUE;

private void boo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = Enum.GetUnderlyingType( color.GetType() ).ToString();

    // it will print 'System.Int32'
    System.Console.WriteLine(str);
}

// the switch case make the compile error - but the color is int 
private void foo()
{
    switch( color )
    {
        case 0:
        {

        }
        break;

        case 1:
        {

        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need braces for your case blocks

Comment: The color is **not** `int`.  It is `Color`, with an underlying type of `int`.  Why do you think enums and ints are exactly the same?

Comment: switch( (int)color ) if you don't like using enum values inside switch

Comment: Why aren't you using case RED: etc??

Comment: @Kevin, this is clearly a stub.  Some people like to regularly use braces so they don't have to fret about colliding variable declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needs to be either:

```
switch( color )
{
    case Color.RED:
        break;
...
}
```

or

```
switch ( (int)color)
{
    case 0:
        break;
...
}
```

Comment: is `RED` some constant of enum type `Color`?

Comment: Should be `case Color.RED:`

Comment: the question was why i need to make the caseing if the type is already int

Comment: @Yanshof enum is not `int`, it is just based on int or even byte if you specify so.

Comment: First, it ISN'T type int.  It's type Color.  As a developer, I'd prefer that people use the enum values instead of int values.  What's the point of using an enum if you aren't going to use it??  If you want it to be an int, just declare it as int and set the value to 1, 2, 3, etc.  Personally, I'd be mad if VS DIDN'T give an error if a cast wasn't required.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check with `Enum Types`

Try This:

```
          private void foo()
           {
            switch( color )
            {
                case Color.RED:
                {

                }
                break;

                case Color.GREEN:
                {

                }
                break;

                case Color.BLUE:
                {

                }
                break;
            }
        }
```